# Convert continuous numbers into fixed intervals in R

Tags: r

I have a series of numbers from 0 to 20 and want to convert them into fixed intervals. I have the following code in R right now:

```
set.seed(21)
x<-sample(0:20, 100, replace=TRUE)
c1<-cut(x,seq(0, 20, by = 5))
table(c1)
```

This gives me:

```
c1  
 (0,5]  (5,10] (10,15] (15,20] 
    24      12      29      32
```

I do not need the frequency. The limits of x and the corresponding interval it should be converted to is given below:

- 17.5-02.5=> 0
- 02.5-07.5=> 5
- 07.5-12.5=> 10
- 12.5-17.5=> 15

Thanks!

Comment: your question can not be understood. You say you need certain intervals, but you are using the way those intervals are created already in your code. You say you do not need a frequency table, but you are using one.  This list you have copied looks like a distorted frequency table, but it does not sum up to 100. I think you should have a look to  `?cut`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over each value and check if the absolute difference from any of the the interval values `c(0, 5, 10, 15)` is less than 2.5:

```
ivl <- c(0, 5, 10, 15)
sapply(x, function(y) ifelse(y > 17.5, 0, ivl[abs(y - ivl) < 2.5]))
```

Another option is to use comparators. You can use base R's `ifelse` for this, but `dplyr::case_when` is a little cleaner:

```r
dplyr::case_when(x < 2.5  | x > 17.5 ~ 0,
                 x > 2.5  & x < 7.5  ~ 5,
                 x > 7.5  & x < 12.5 ~ 10,
                 x > 12.5 & x < 17.5 ~ 15)
```

In both cases you end up with the following vector:

```r
  [1]  0  0 10 15 15  0 10  0  5 10  5  5  5  0  0 10 15 10 15  0 10  5  5 10  5 15  0  0 15  0
 [31] 15  0 10 10  0 15  5  5  5 10 10  0  0 15  5  5  5  5 10 10 15 10 10 15  5  0 10  0  5  0
 [61]  0 10 10  0 10  0  5  0 15  5 15 15 10  5 15  0  5  5  0  5  5  0 15  5  5 10  5 15  0 10
 [91] 10  0 15 15  0 15  0 10  5  5
```

Comment: This proved to be the correct answer. Thanks @gersht!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are looking for this interval

```
[0,2.5]   (2.5,7.5]  (7.5,12.5] (12.5,17.5]   (17.5,20]
```

which is not clear, as you want one interval from 17.5 - 2.5,
here is the result of `cut` and the corresponding frequency table.

```r
set.seed(21)
x<-sample(0:20, 100, replace=TRUE)
# c1<-cut(x, seq(0, 20, by = 5))

cut(x, breaks=c(0, 2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 17.5, 20), include.lowest=TRUE)
#>   [1] [0,2.5]     [0,2.5]     (7.5,12.5]  (12.5,17.5] (12.5,17.5] (17.5,20]  
#>   [7] (7.5,12.5]  (17.5,20]   (2.5,7.5]   (7.5,12.5]  (2.5,7.5]   (2.5,7.5]  
#>  [13] (2.5,7.5]   [0,2.5]     [0,2.5]     (7.5,12.5]  (12.5,17.5] (7.5,12.5] 
#>  [19] (12.5,17.5] [0,2.5]     (7.5,12.5]  (2.5,7.5]   (2.5,7.5]   (7.5,12.5] 
#>  [25] (2.5,7.5]   (12.5,17.5] [0,2.5]     [0,2.5]     (12.5,17.5] [0,2.5]    
#>  [31] (12.5,17.5] [0,2.5]     (7.5,12.5]  (7.5,12.5]  (17.5,20]   (12.5,17.5]
#>  [37] (2.5,7.5]   (2.5,7.5]   (2.5,7.5]   (7.5,12.5]  (7.5,12.5]  [0,2.5]    
#>  [43] (17.5,20]   (12.5,17.5] (2.5,7.5]   (2.5,7.5]   (2.5,7.5]   (2.5,7.5]  
#>  [49] (7.5,12.5]  (7.5,12.5]  (12.5,17.5] (7.5,12.5]  (7.5,12.5]  (12.5,17.5]
#>  [55] (2.5,7.5]   [0,2.5]     (7.5,12.5]  (17.5,20]   (2.5,7.5]   (17.5,20]  
#>  [61] (17.5,20]   (7.5,12.5]  (7.5,12.5]  (17.5,20]   (7.5,12.5]  [0,2.5]    
#>  [67] (2.5,7.5]   [0,2.5]     (12.5,17.5] (2.5,7.5]   (12.5,17.5] (12.5,17.5]
#>  [73] (7.5,12.5]  (2.5,7.5]   (12.5,17.5] (17.5,20]   (2.5,7.5]   (2.5,7.5]  
#>  [79] (17.5,20]   (2.5,7.5]   (2.5,7.5]   [0,2.5]     (12.5,17.5] (2.5,7.5]  
#>  [85] (2.5,7.5]   (7.5,12.5]  (2.5,7.5]   (12.5,17.5] [0,2.5]     (7.5,12.5] 
#>  [91] (7.5,12.5]  [0,2.5]     (12.5,17.5] (12.5,17.5] [0,2.5]     (12.5,17.5]
#>  [97] [0,2.5]     (7.5,12.5]  (2.5,7.5]   (2.5,7.5]  
#> Levels: [0,2.5] (2.5,7.5] (7.5,12.5] (12.5,17.5] (17.5,20]

table(cut(x, breaks=c(0, 2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 17.5, 20), include.lowest=TRUE))
#> 
#>     [0,2.5]   (2.5,7.5]  (7.5,12.5] (12.5,17.5]   (17.5,20] 
#>          18          28          24          20          10
```